# Finding a finite set from two uncountable sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am trying to find a finite set such that an infinite set A and an infinite set B in $A - B$ will result in a finite set.

I saw an answer from someone else as all reals $>=0$ - all reals $> 0$ which doesn't make sense to me. Isn't that indeterminate since it is like infinity minus infinity? Also wouldn't it leave all reals between 0 and 1 which is an infinite set?

Comment: Consider the set of natural numbers: $\mathbb{N}$ and the set $X = \mathbb{N} \backslash \{3,4,5\}$.

Comment: Here you don't have to think about cardinality. Just think that $\Bbb R_{+}\cup$ {$0$}-$\Bbb R_{+}=${$0$} which is finite set

Comment: @Newb What does that mean? \3,4,5?

Comment: @Dimitris Isn't that infinity minus infinity though?

Comment: @PaulthePirate:  $A\setminus B$ is a common notation for the set difference, which perhaps you write as $A-B$, and it means the set of elements of $A$ that are not in $B$.  The concept of infinity need not be considered for this to be defined.  In Newb's example, $X=\mathbb N\setminus \{3,4,5\}$ means that $X$ is the set of positive integers that are not equal to $3$, $4$, or $5$, i.e., $X=\{1,2,6,7,8,\ldots\}$.

Comment: It's infinity minus infinity in let's say "numbers". But in set theory we don't have algebraic operations. At least nonone that i know of. Here you just throw away a set from another. It doesn't concern you if there are infinite

Answer (score 1):

The definition of the set $A-B$ is the set of elements of $A$ which are not in $B$. If we consider a real number $x$ such that $x\in A$ and $x\not\in B$, then $x\ge 0$ and $x\not > 0$, so $x\le 0$. The only real number $x$ satisfying this is $x=0$, so the set $A-B=\{0\}$. It wouldn't leave numbers between $0$ and $1$, as these are in set $B$, which is not allowed. It is important to distinguish between considering the difference of two sets, which is well defined, and could result in a finite set, and the difference of two real numbers or "infinities", which is in general not necessarily defined or related to the first definition.

Answer (score 1):

It's easiest to use a **countably infinite** set. The reals are uncountably infinite, so taking subsets of the reals might be problematic.

Take, for example, $\mathbb{N}$, the natural numbers. Then let's define $X = \mathbb{N} \backslash \{3,4,5\}$.

Simply, $\mathbb{N} \backslash (\mathbb{N}\backslash\{3,4,5\}) = \{3,4,5\}$ which is finite.

You can also use other constructions, using the reals if you wish - for example, Dimitris' comment on your question is good. The trick to this sort of question is to select an infinite set $A$, and then a set $B$ that differs from $A$ in some small respect, e.g. by only one element.

Answer (score 0):

The set of reals which are greater than or equal to $0$ includes $0$.  The set of reals greater than $0$ is different from the first set only by not including $0$.  The difference of these two sets is the set containing $0$, which is finite, having exactly one element.

Answer (score -1):

If you remove all real numbers greater than $0$, then you do not leave real numbers between $0$ and $1$.  Numbers greater than $0$ and less than $1$ are greater than $0$, hence they will be removed.  The answer someone else showed you would leave $\{0\}$ as the set difference.

There is nothing indeterminate.  Given sets $A$ and $B$, $A\setminus B=\{a\in A: a\not\in B\}$ is definitely defined regardless of the sizes of $A$ and $B$.  If $F$ is your favorite finite set, and $B$ is your favorite infinite set such that $B\cap F =\varnothing$, then with $A = F\cup B$, you will have both $A$ and $B$ infinite and $A\setminus B = F$.

For example, if $F = \{e,\pi, \sqrt 2\}$, $B=\{2,3,5,7,\ldots\}$ is the set of prime numbers, and $A=F\cup B = \{e,\pi,\sqrt 2, 2,3,5,7,\ldots\}$, then $A$ and $B$ are infinite and $A\setminus B = F$.